# PHP Intelephense 'undefined method' issues

Tags: php, polymorphism, intelephense

I recently switched to an IDE that supports PHP's **Intelephense**.
There are two issues showing up that I don't know how to resolve (note, however, that the code executes correctly).

---

#### #1. Undefined method 'myfunc'

```php
$myobj = $this->myfactory->createObject($myparams);
```

Essentially, I'm using a library that uses Factories to create the needed dependencies. I access the factory in question like stated above, where `createObject`'s return type is an interface. The default class that `implements` this factory has the additional method `myfunc`, so I can validly call `my_func()`, but the IDE shows an error because it obviously can't find it in the interface.

**Is there no easy way to cast the interface to the expected concrete class?**

---

#### #2. Undefined method 'get'

```php
class MyClass{
    //...

    static function withAdditionalParams($myParams){
       return function ($defaultParamA, $defaultParamB) use ($myParams) {
           return $this->get(self::class)->__invoke($defaultParamA, $defaultParamB, $myParams);
       };
    }
}
```

While being similar to the problem above, this one is a bit more complex. Since we're dealing with closures, the `$this` in this context actually refers to a *DI Container*, while Intelephense thinks it's referring to a `MyClass` instance.

**Is there no way to explicitly say what `$this` refers to in this specific context?**

---

Any help or advice is highly appreciated, thank you!!